# Why can't you use margins or padding for vertical centering?

Tags: css, standards

Okay, so like anyone who has ever had to use css, I'm aware that You can't vertically center an element dynamically other than with "fake table" from display-table. (By dynamically I mean "if you don't know the centered element, or the container's size, or both".)

What I'd like to understand is *why*? I have tried goggling but all this finds is workaround, when what interests me is the philosophy behind such a strange decision.

So, WHY can one use margin:auto to center horizontally, but not vertically? As far as I know, you can do EVERYTHING in the box model to a table cell that you can do to a div, but only the former will ever let you center vertically. Why would one ever write a presentation language standard (as far as I can tell, it says that vertical "auto" for margins and padding is equivalent to 0) that does that?

Comment: You can vertically center an element dynamically without fake tables, actually; it just needs to have either a fixed height or an extra element to apply `vertical-align: middle` to.

Comment: @minitech: That only works on table cells, and slightly different on inline elements. It [does not affect block elements](http://jsfiddle.net/eGGZu/3/). See [Understanding vertical-align, or "How (Not) To Vertically Center Content"](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html).

Comment: @minitech Plus that is completely unrelated to my question as to why margins and padding weren't given that capability to begin with.

Comment: @animuson: No, actually, the fixed height method works on block elements, and there's actually a way to hack `vertical-align` into them.

Comment: @Circeus: That's why it was a *comment*. ;) *"I'm aware that You can't vertically center an element dynamically other than with "fake table" from display-table."*

Comment: I think question is why `margin:0 auto;` works and `margin:auto 0;` doesn't.

Comment: @minitech: Can you show me an example where that works?

Comment: @animuson: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/AV7jR/

Comment: @minitech: That's not using the vertical-align property...

Comment: Does it ever make sense to use padding for centering things?

Comment: @animuson: Ah, I forgot a part on that last comment: "... but I don't remember how to do it."

Answer (score 3):

Because, the width of an element can be determined as soon as the element is created. A percentage is just (percent * parent width) and an absolute width is just that width. We know the width. Height, however, is not determined until after all the content inside that element has been rendered and the heights of those elements and content have also been determined.

While the width *can* be determined by the element's content, the height is *always* determined by the element's content.

From: [Understanding vertical-align, or "How (Not) To Vertically Center Content"](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html)

> HTML layout traditionally was not designed to specify vertical behavior. By its very nature, it scales width-wise, and the content flows to an appropriate height based on the available width. Traditionally, horizontal sizing and layout is easy; vertical sizing and layout was derived from that.

Therefore, an element cannot accurately determine what its margin (or padding) on the top and bottom need to be before its content is completely rendered. Since those are applied first so that any other elements and content inside it can also be rendered appropriately, the values `auto` get ignored.

Comment: This implies that if you fix the height of an element by using style="height: x;", then you should be able to vertically center it ... right?

Comment: No, because if the content expands past the specified height, it will still expand. The only place that logic would make sense is on `max-height`, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't horizontally center a element without knowing its width either.

Here is a way to center an element horizontally and vertically:

```css
#main {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
}
```

Of course you could use other values such as `width: 80%`, consequently the `top` should be `10%`.

Have a look here for dynamic height (quick  search haven't thoroughly read it): http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/center-div-with-dynamic-height/